# WordPress Customizer Default Image

Tags: php, theme-development, themes, theme-customizer

I'm trying to set a default image to a Customizer image with the code below but image does not display.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'header_image' , '<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/default-image.jpg' ); ?>">
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this if it will work.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'header_image' , get_template_directory_uri().'/images/default-image.jpg' ); ?>">
```

Comment: Actually, you should use `header_image()`. This will then automatically return the `default-image` as supplied when defining the `custom-header` theme support. So this can be as simple as: `<img src="<?php header_image(); ?>">`. _But_ then you should yet again consider using `the_header_image_tag()` for that, but then yet again, as of 4.7 you should use `the_custom_header_markup()`.